# 2D Histogram normalized for probabilities

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a 2D data set and I would like to plot a 2D histogram, with each cell on the histogram representing the probability of the data point. Hence to obtain the probability, I need to normalize the histogram data so they sum to 1. Here is what I have for an example, from the 2Dhistogram documentation:

```
xedges = [0,1,3,5]
yedges = [0,2,3,4,6]
#create edges of bins

#create random data points
x=np.random.normal(2,1,100)
y=np.random.normal(1,1,100)
H,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=(xedges,yedges))
#setting normed=True in histogram2d doesn't seem to do what I need

H=H.T
#weirdly histogram2d swaps the x,y axis, so transpose to restore it.

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
plt.imshow(H,interpolation='nearest',origin='low',extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1],yedges[0],yedges[-1]])
plt.show()
```

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzWib.png)

Firstly, a `np.sum(H)` gives something like 86. I would like each cell to represent the probability of the data lying on that binned cell, so they should all sum to 1. Additionally, how do you plot a legend mapping the color intensity to its value with `imshow`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `normed` argument. Also, per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) the values in H will be calculated as `bin_count / sample_count / bin_area`. So we calculate the areas of the bins and multiply it by H to get the probability for the bin.

```
xedges = [0,1,3,5]
yedges = [0,2,3,4,6]
# create edges of bins

x = np.random.normal(2, 1, 100) # create random data points
y = np.random.normal(1, 1, 100)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xedges, yedges), normed=True)
areas = np.matmul(np.array([np.diff(xedges)]).T, np.array([np.diff(yedges)]))
# setting normed=True in histogram2d doesn't seem to do what I need

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
im = plt.imshow(H*areas, interpolation='nearest', origin='low', extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If I set `normed=True`, `np.sum(H)` gives something like 0.33, which is wrong. It seems like the `normed=True` statement doesn't do exactly what I require.

Comment: Well your bins only capture about 33% of the observations which is why it doesn't add up to 1.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean about capturing only a fraction of the observations? I group the data points into the bins, and then would like to normalize the bins themselves.

Comment: My previous comment was incorrect (answer edited). The reason that H was not summing to 1 is not that observations aren't being captured but rather because the weighted average bin area was about 3 in your example. By standardizing the bin areas to be 1, you can see that H sums up to 1. If you want to get a sum of 1 using non-standard bin areas, you will have to weight the values in H by their respective bin's area.

Comment: Just edited to generalize for varying bin areas like in your example. If this answers your question, please kindly accept the answer.

Comment: I initially did not understand how 2dhistogram normed the bins based on the area. That cleared up a lot. Thank you! I have accepted the answer.